# netsuite saved search suitelet trying to get value but cant

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Im currently trying to resolve an issue where I cant get a value from a suitelet from a savedsearch within Netsuite.

```
"unitprice": 12.6,
    "salesdescription": "cheap item",
    "custrecord_pm_record_name": {
    "internalid": 2,
    "name": "test item"
}
```

Basically I'm just trying to get the values internalid and name that is within the array above.

If anyone knows Netsuite and how to extract this value that would be great, or if there is a typical way to grab this with vanilla JS that would be awesome also

```
var _searchId = 'customsearch_pm_item_record_loader';
        //itemFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('displayName',null, 'contains', _searchTerm )); //
        var rs = nlapiSearchRecord('item', _searchId, itemFilters,columns);
        for ( var i = 0; rs != null && i < rs.length; i++)
        {   
            var rowObj = {};
            rowObj.id = rs[i].getValue('internalid');
            rowObj.custitem_dwr_co_dis  = rs[i].getValue('custitem_dwr_co_dis');
            rowObj.salesdescription     = rs[i].getValue('salesdescription');
            rowObj.displayName          = rs[i].getValue('displayName');
            rowObj.itemid               = rs[i].getValue('itemid');
            rowObj.unitPrice            = rs[i].getValue('unitprice', 'pricing');   // unit price
            rowObj.basePrice            = rs[i].getValue('baseprice');
            rowObj.productImage         = rs[i].getText('custitem50');
            retObj.push(rowObj);
        }
        var _jsonString = JSON.stringify(rs);
```

Comment: i dont understand, these values are already there in the array, are you asking how to read JSON property values from an array i.e. rowObj or JSON equivalent of rs?

Comment: Also, what is the point of rowObj when you are doing JSON.stringify() on rs? What do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the text and id of a list/record field. For some generic code (where you don't know whether or not you have a list/record result) I do something like this:

```
var _searchId = 'customsearch_pm_item_record_loader';
//itemFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('displayName',null, 'contains', _searchTerm )); //
var rs = nlapiSearchRecord('item', _searchId, itemFilters, columns);
function getResolver(result){
    return function(fld,join,agg){
        var txt = result.getText(fld,join,agg);
        if(txt) return {
            id: result.getValue(fld,join,agg),
            value:txt;
        };
        return result.getValue(fld,join,agg);
    };
}
var retObj = [];
for (var i = 0; rs != null && i < rs.length; i++) {
    var resolve = getResolver(rs[i]); 
    retObj.push({
        id : rs[i].getId(),
        custitem_dwr_co_dis : resolve('custitem_dwr_co_dis'),
        salesdescription : resolve('salesdescription'),
        displayName : resolve('displayName'),
        itemid : resolve('itemid'),
        unitPrice : resolve('unitprice', 'pricing'), // unit price
        basePrice : resolve('baseprice'),
        productImage : resolve('custitem50')
    });

}
var _jsonString = JSON.stringify(retObj);
```